# How to push custom state to window on page navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a project where navigation is solely based on ajax requests. Let's say, I've three pages, `Menu.html`, `View.html` and `Edit.html`. User navigate to Menu.html after successful login. There he can choose options to land on `view.html`. From `view.html`, he can choose more options to edit them on edit.html.
Now, if the user presses 'back' button on browser, he is taken to `menu.html` rather than on `view.html`. I assume, he is landing on menu.html too only because I've redirections on index page.

So, I googled and found that I could use `window.replaceState`. But I don't know how exactly so that when user clicks back button on edit.html, he is taken back to view.html and not menu.html.
Thanks

Comment: you question is too broad, could you supply some example code please?

Comment: I mean, I want to update the broswer history on click event of my divs or anchor tags so that when user clicks 'back' button on browser, he gets to the last visited page (that was fetched as a result of previous ajax calls) and not to the page he had started his browsing with. Do I still sound confusing?

Comment: it's still too theoretical - without knowing if you're using pushState, hashtags, iframes or whatever else to accomplish your task, it's not so easy to provide a helpful answer - the wording "AJAX requests" can mean any of those, and more

Comment: I'm not using any iframes. I'm simply calling window.location.replace to update page's URL. For example, say, I'm moving user to the menu.html from index.html, using window.location='menu.html', after index.html authenticates user through an ajax call to server. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use html5's pushstate and popstate

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

http://html5demos.com/history

Comment: 'window.pushState' got my issue solved. Thanks for your help, anyway. :)

Comment: @eddy no worries, happy to help. Kindly select the answer, if it resolved your problem